# Amazon RDS DB Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

since my last post was closed and the indian youtubers still don't help me find salvation, I'll ask the same question again and give you more info.

My custom parameter-group [parameter-group-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6o7Q.png). Many tutorial say, that I should set the value of 'log_bin_trust_function_creators' to 1, but I don't have that, when I use a MSSQL server.

My option Group looks like this [option-group-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GcTv.png). In both of my buckets is a file named 'incca.bak' from which I want to restore files from [bucket-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwJqY.png).

In my custom security group I added an inbound rule for my IP [security-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04fAl.png).

Login is possible as is creating a new DB as shown here [login-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C90r.png)[newDB-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6i6.png).

Restoring a DB end in this error [restoreDB-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYeRJ.png) and if I do it by query it looks like this [query-restore-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhpm6.png)

**(Full Error here: [2020-06-05 12:39:22.310] Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request. [2020-06-05 12:39:22.637] Task has been aborted [2020-06-05 12:39:22.640] Access Denied")**

Again, I have never done this before, and I am sorry if that may seem simple, but I hope I provided enough Info for some help.

Comment: I wanna add my connectivity and configuration tabs, but I can't put any more links in the post, so sorry, but trust me, everything is configured right, the db is public and I think all the other information is provided. I don't know why my greetings at the top get deleted, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Access denied message in RDS SQL Server during restore refers to the problem that the policy with which your IAM role for backup restore option group does not have correct policy required to S3 bucket.

Have you verified if your IAM policy is in line with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Enabling.IAM

Comment: I am not using IAM for authentication. I only have the master user.

https://imgur.com/vTyru0q   

https://imgur.com/HCWHqVR